# How do I quickly access the interface version of my swift file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

Since Swift files don't have a header, it can quickly get cluttered and hard to see just the `public` and `internal` methods that represent the interface of that file/class.

Xcode actually generates an interface file that can be found by clicking the `Assistant Editor`, then selecting the `Counterparts` type and you'll see the `MySwiftFile.swift (Interface)` file that you can check out.

Does anyone know an easier way to access this interface file? Maybe with a shortcut? I can't seem to find it using Cmd+Shift+O or other means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click the assistant editor (use the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to show the editor) and thereafter use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> to navigate to your `.swift` interface file in the assistant window. It's not an immediate short-cut, but possibly better than navigation by clicks/mouse/touchpad.

Comment: That works on normal Objc files to switch between the .h and .m files, but that's not working for swift files.

Comment: @teradyl Updated answer. The works for swift, and is as close I can get to the shortcut behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: @teradyl thanks for the edit, I slightly edited it myself as it seems we still have to actually click in the assistant editor (even after opening it by cmd+opt+enter shortcut) prior to navigating it with ctrl+cmd+ ->. Btw, have you found any other possible shortcuts, or does this answer your question?

Comment: It looks like this is the best option at the moment, we'll have to wait until those radars madmir posted get attended to!

Answer (score 12):

Open generated interface: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Go back: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. This is the most useful answer I found for Xcode 13 on this page. The other answers are too old and did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In no way, except for menu selection "Navigate / Jump to Generated Interface"

[Xcode cannot assign key binding to "Jump to Generated Interface"](https://openradar.appspot.com/24091116)

[Allow to switch between Swift generated interface and original source via shortcut](http://www.openradar.me/22558104)

Comment: It worked for me like a piece of cake, Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a work-around for this.

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts

Hit "+", select Xcode as the application, "Jump to Generated Interface" as the menu title, and then select your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Seems promising, but it didn't work for me. Where did you get this information?

Comment: Its weird, it seems like sometimes it doesn't work for a file and I have to open the Navigate menu (I don't need to select anything) and then it starts to work. The shortcut should show up in the menu.

Comment: It works, but after that you set shortcut in "System Preferences", go to Xcode and switch two, three times manually from menu->Navigate, after that the shot shortcut. WORKED FOR ME. ;)